# Show ProgressBar while task is running

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to show a progress bar only while a task is running, this is my code

```
public void onButtonPressed() {
        //loadingSpinner is a ProgressBar already instantiated whit visibility GONE;
        loadingSpinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        boolean resultFromAsyncTask = AnotherClass.AsyncTaskMethod();
        if(resultFromAsyncTask ) {
            loadingSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //do something
            finish();
        }else{
            loadingSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //Show alert
        }
    }
```

The problem is that when I change visibility the first time nothing happens. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Don't over complicate things, `AsyncTask` has all the methods you need to accomplish this.

Set `loadingSpinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` inside `onPreExecute` of your AsyncTask and set `loadingSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);` inside `onPostExecute`.

Like this:

```
private class YourTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> { 

    @Override protected void onPreExecute(){
        loadingSpinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } 


    @Override 
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) { 
        //Do background work 
    }

    @Override protected void onPostExecute(String result) { 
        loadingSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

}
```

Comment: This seems to be the simpliest way and I tried but doesn't work. The spinner is visible only in onPostExecute phase (I've added a Thread.sleep just before setVisibility(View.GONE) to see it)

Comment: @NicolasP please update your question and provide your code how you implemented it.

Answer (score 1):

Your calling an Async task but using it like a regular function. You cant base something off the result of an Async task like that, the code will just run right over it and execute the next lines.
What you want is to show the progress bar, then start your task without a return like that. You need something like a broadcast from your onPostExecute to call back to your calling class to let it know when its done.
Edit** in this case since a bool defaults to false, it is using that value in your if statement and hiding it as soon as you show it.

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Notsileous, call a method from the `onPostExecute` method of your AsyncTask that does some UI work. You may need to wrap that code in a `runOnUiThread` for it to work.

To exemplify with your code:

```
public void onButtonPressed() {
        //loadingSpinner is a ProgressBar already instantiated whit visibility GONE;
        loadingSpinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        AnotherClass.AsyncTaskMethod().execute();
}
[...]
public void doneLoading(boolean resultFromAsyncTask ) {
   runOnUiThread {
       if(resultFromAsyncTask ) {
            loadingSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //do something
            finish();
        }else{
            loadingSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //Show alert
        }  
    }
}
[...]
AsyncTask postExecuteMethod(boolean executionResult) {
 doneLoading(executionResult);
}
[...]
```

Hope this helps clarify! :)